Why if extend screen of PC on touchscreen, the touch position is wrong?
I bought a touchscreen with the one to extend the desktop so that on the left on the laptop I use the cursor while on the right (on the second touch screen) I use the touch. However, if I move with the touch the cursor spans the entire desktop with the wrong position (touch all the way to the left = the cursor goes all the way to the left on the PC screen, touch all the way to the right = correct position i.e. all the way to the right of the touch). On Windows it works correctly.
Thanks for the help
OS: 
mario@MarioNB:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

Thouchscreen: Arcus Technology LTD21 1920x1080


It is a mapping problem. To solve it, you can use the xinput map-to-output command if you are using an X-server, or you can set the gsettings property, as explained in this answer for Wayland.
